# не работает автозагрузка классов (возможно) в php

Tags: php, автозагрузка

*Заранее извиняюсь за возможные ошибки в терминах*

Не знаю даже что именно не работает, при попытке зайти на localhost ничего не выходит, код полностью из книги "php и mysql, 25 уроков для начинающих" В. Дронова. **Это код из файла index.php:**

```
<?php
$base_path = __DIR__ . '/';
require_once $base_path . 'modules/settings.php';

function my_autoloader(string $class_name) {
   global $base_path;
   require_once $base_path . 'modules/' . $class_name . '.php';
}
spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');

require_once $base_path . 'modules/router.php';    
?>
```

**файлы из папки /modules:**

/modules/router.php

```
<?php
$request_path = $_GET['route'];
if ($request_path == '') {
    $ctr = new \Controllers\Images();
    $ctr->lst();
}
else {
    $index = (integer)$request_path;
    $ctr = new \Controllers\Images();
    $ctr->item($index);
}
?>
```

/modules/helpers.php

```
<?php
namespace Helpers { 
    function render(string $template, array $context) {
        global $base_path;
        extract($context);
        require $base_path . 'Modules/Templates/' . $template . '.php';
    }
    function get_fragment_path(string $fragment): string {
        global $base_path;
        return $base_path . 'Modules/Templates/' . $fragment . '.inc.php';
    }
}
```

/modules/settings.php

```
<?php 
namespace Settings { 
    const SITE_NAME = 'Фотогалерея';
    const IMAGE_PATH = '/images/';
}
?>
```

**файлы из папки /modules/controllers:**

/modules/controllers/basecontroller.php

```
<?php
namespace Controllers {
    require_once $base_path . 'modules/helpers.php';

    class BaseController {
        protected function contex_append(array &$context) {}

        protected function render(string $template, array $context) {
            $this->context_append($context);
            \Helpers\render($template, $context);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

/modules/controllers/images.php

```
<?php
namespace Controllers {
    class Images extends BaseController {
        function list() {
            $ctx = ['list' => new \Models\Image()];
            $this->render('list', $ctx);
        }

        function item(int $index) {
            $item = \Models\Image::get_image($index);
            $ctx = ['item' => $item, 'site_title' => $item['desc']];
            $this->render('item', $ctx);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**/modules/models/image.php**

```
<?php
namespace Models {
    class Image implements \Iterator {
        private const DATA = [
            ['src' => '200804282020.jpg', 'desc' => 'Цветы кактуса'],
            ['src' => '200807192032.jpg', 'desc' => 'Пустынная аллея в запущенном парке'],
            ['src' => '200901092053.jpg', 'desc' => 'Зимний закат'],
            ['src' => '201410131614.jpg', 'desc' => 'Роза'],
            ['src' => '201506152037.jpg', 'desc' => 'Памятник сусликам'],
            ['src' => '201709180821.jpg', 'desc' => 'Бронзовые бегемотики'],
            ['src' => '201709252026.jpg', 'desc' => 'Кот ученый'],
            ['src' => '201710242002.jpg', 'desc' => 'Памятник собаке-поводырю'],
            ['src' => '201802131844.jpg', 'desc' => 'Блинная скульптура в кафе']
        ];

        private $current_index = 0;
        
        function current() {
            return self::DATA[$this->current_index];
        }
        
        function key() {
            return $this->current_index;
        }

        function next() {
            $this->current_index++;
        }

        function rewind() {
            $this->current_index = 0;
        }

        function valid() {
            return isset(self::DATA[$this->current_index]);
        }
        
        static function get_image(int $index): array {
            return self::DATA[$index];
        }
    }
}
```

**папка /modules/templates:**

/modules/templates/item.php

```
<?php require \Helpers\get_fragment_path('__header') ?>
<h2><?php echo $item['desc'] ?></h2>
<p><a href="/">На главную</a></p>
<section id="gallery-item">
    <img src="<?php echo \Settings\IMAGE_PATH . $item['src'] ?>">
</section>
<p><a href="/">На главную</a></p>
<?php require \Helpers\get_fragment_path('__footer') ?>
```

/modules/templates/list.php

```
<?php require \Helpers\get_fragment_path('__header') ?>
<section id="gallery">
    <?php
        foreach ($list as $i => $ing) {
    ?>
    <a href="/<?php echo $i ?>/">
        <img src="<?php echo \Settings\IMAGE_PATH . $img['src'] ?>" title="<?php echo $img['desc'] ?>">
    </a>
    <?php } ?>
</section>
<?php require \Helpers\get_fragment_path('__footer') ?>
```

в файлах __header.inc.php и __footer.inc.php нет ничего важного.

Comment: в index.php вы попадаете, проверяли?

Comment: нет, не попадает

Comment: тогда проблема с этим кодом не связана. смотрите, как настроен сервер, куда показывает localhost и тп

Comment: в том то и дело что сервер нормально работает, и все что я запускал раньше через index.php работает, простейшие команды типа echo из index.php тоже запускаются

Comment: *в index.php нет, не попадает* и  *echo из index.php тоже запускаютс* ?

Comment: если запускать указанный код из index.php то не попадает, но если в файле index.php все снести и просто написать что нибудь вроде  <?php echo '...'; ?> то localhost/index.php работает

Comment: ну, если не можете нормальным отладчиком воспользоваться, поставьте echo <название модуля> в каждого файла и посмотрите, что происходит.

Comment: я еще не дошел до отладчиков, сейчас попробую ваш вариант